# Ruby on rails importing wordpress from jekyll error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, rubygems, jekyll

I am trying to import from my self-hosted `wordpress` blog to `Jekyll` and have the `xml` file `test.wordpress.2014-08-05.xml`. I am running the following command for that-

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import"; JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run({ "source" => "test.wordpress.2014-08-05.xml" })'
```

but getting this wierd error -

```
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting tASSOC
```

I have no idea why. I already have jekyll installed.

Comment: [Related] http://stackoverflow.com/q/31216857/1577396