# Import wordpress posts in jekyll

Tags: ruby, wordpress, jekyll, blogs

I already have a blog maintained by wordpress. Now, I am planning to move my blog posts to jekyll.

I already forked jekyll basic blog template from [jekyllnow](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now)

and then I tried to import all my blog posts from wordpress to jekyll using [Wordpress to jekyll exporter](https://github.com/benbalter/wordpress-to-jekyll-exporter) plugin as explained in this [smashing magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/01/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/).

> To export from WordPress, I’d highly recommend Ben Balter’s one-click WordPress to Jekyll Exporter plugin.

This didn't work for me.

So, my second attempt was to export the wordpress posts in an xml file as explained in the same smashing magazine article.

> The other option is to export all content in the “Tools” menu of the WordPress dashboard, and then importing it with [Jekyll’s importer](http://import.jekyllrb.com/docs/wordpress/).

So, I first exported only my posts from wordpress to xml.

```
Wordpress Admin -> Tools -> Export -> checked posts -> Download xml file
```

and placed that xml file in my project folder, which is with directory name `kamlekar.github.io`.

and then in Ruby's command prompt, I cd to my project folder and run the following code as shown in the below image:

[image]

As you can see, I am getting the following error:

> -e:1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting tASSOC

The command I wrote is

> `ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-import"; JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run({ "source" => "wpexport.xml"} )`

I am not sure why this error is coming. I already installed `gem install github-pages` and `gem install jekyll-import`.

Here is a [dummy xml file](https://gist.github.com/kamlekar/716370aa0f2cbe5faba8) to reproduce the issue.

---

I am on Windows 8 with Ruby 1.9.2 installed.

Comment: Can you please change the command and error message to be code-formatted text instead of an image?  We can't cut-and-paste the command from an image.

Comment: @WayneConrad `ruby -rubygems -e 'require "jekyll-imp
ort"; JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run({ "source" => "wpexport.xml"}
)'`

Comment: Thanks!  (it ought to go in the question itself, though).  Once I change the cut-paste error "imp ort" to "import", the command runs perfectly in Linux with Ruby 2.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the same code in `irb` (*Interactive Ruby*)

```
$ irb
```

It gave me some detailed error that I need to install `hpricot`. So, I installed hpricot.

```
irb > exit
$ cd <project_folder>
$ gem install hpricot
```

But still the ruby command prompt was giving me error. So, I ran the importer code through `irb`. As [explained by Wayne](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/24259625#24259625)

```
$ irb
irb>  require "jekyll-import"; JekyllImport::Importers::WordpressDotCom.run({ "source" => "wpexport.xml"} )
```

That worked!!

But still in my imported posts, there were characters like `});` at the top-left of page. Which I removed by visiting each post file in `_posts/`and removed `options: {}` line from the meta content of the posts.

Thanks to [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720164/jonathan-allard) and [Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238886/wayne-conrad) for there support in [Ruby chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44914/ruby-sometimes-on-rails).

Comment: You're welcome!  I want to add a disclaimer for others who will read this: SO is the primary place to get help for Ruby problems.  The Ruby chat room is mainly for chat; the people there may or may not help with a Ruby problem, as they like.  The same rules apply there as apply here: The more effort you put into your problem/question, the more likely you are to get a solution.